# Change video start when 3d tracking

Tags: animation, tracking, effects

I made an animated a model in a blender that I will be putting into a video using 3d tracking.  The problem is that the video and animation are not synced up like I want them to; all I need to do is to, for example, start the video at frame -10, I don't want to cut the video so it is easier to work with and play around with the timing, and my animation uses some glitch(feature?) that only lasts from frame 1 to 100, so I can't move my animation. is there any way of changing when the video starts?

Answer (score 1):

See **Footage Settings** in *Movie Clip* editor, *N-Panel*

[image]